# Create a function to accept a 2D array and return an object showing all keys:values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is for an assignment. Please DO NOT down vote. Everybody had to start somewhere, and each person learns differently.

The function must accept a 2D array (an array of pairs) in this specific format:

```
array = [[1, 2], [3, 4], ['nice', 'free'], [5, 6]];
```

array can be any length, but in pairs as shown above.

function must return: `{1:2, 3:4, nice: 'free', 5:6}`

This is the code I've devised so far:

```js
function keyValue(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
     pairs = {
  [array[i][0]]: array[i][1]
     };
        console.log(pairs);
 }
}

keyValue([[1, 2], [3, 4], ['nice', 'free'], [5, 6]]);
```

The result shows: keyValue `(array)'returns':Object {1: 2}, Object {3: 4},  Object {nice: 'free'}, Object {5: 6}`

'console.log' shows all the keys:values; however 'return' would only show the first key:value set; i.e `{1:2}`

I'm not sure if I created multiple objects, each with its own key:value, perhaps the reason 'return' only showed one set of key:value

OR

If I did create just one object, I need to use the 'return' function to show the entire set of keys:values for that object. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i made it to work with what you have.

Comment: you are creating all new objects for every pair, the wanted result shows only one object.

Comment: Simply use `new Map(array)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its much simpler:

```
function keyValue(array) {
var obj={};
for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    obj[array[i][0]]=array[i][1];       
}
 return obj;
}

keyValue([[1, 2], [3, 4], ['nice', 'free'], [5, 6]]);
```

Simply create an object, and assign new properties to it in the loop...

Comment: Worked perfectly! I was so close, but yet so far! I did try something very similar to your code, except that I placed the 'var obj = {}' inside of the 'for loop'; which returned only one key:value set, but everything else was identical.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an empty object and assign new properties for every pair you have in the array.

Beside that, I suggest to declare all variables in advance.

Basically this, in pseudo code

```
declare object

iterate array
    assign new key/value pair to object

return object
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating all are New Object.All are separated object .you need to push with some array of each pair object then retrieve the first object with `Array[0]` .Try like below snippet

```js
function keyValue(array) {
var res=[];
    for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
     pairs = {
  [array[i][0]]: array[i][1]
     };
        res.push(pairs); // pushing to array
 }
  console.log(res[0]) // retrive the first object
}

keyValue([[1, 2], [3, 4], ['nice', 'free'], [5, 6]]);
```